# Compute mean and standard deviation over multiple 3D matrices

Tags: matlab

I got a 119x31 cell array. Each cell contains a 91x109x91 matrix and I want to compute the std and the mean over all 31 columns per row. The result should be a 32nd 91x109x91 per row containing the standard deviation values or mean values respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over all rows and then use `cat` to concatenate the the matrices into a fourth dimension, to which you then can use `mean` and `std`.

```
%Build some test data
A{10,5} = randn(7,8,9);
A(:,:) = {randn(7,8,9)};

Ae = A; Av = A;%Make resulting cellarrays
Ae{1,end+1}={}; Av{1,end+1}={}; %Make room for one additional entry
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    B = cat(4,A{i,:}); %Matrix now in 4D
    E = mean(B,4);
    V = std(B,[],4);
    Ae{i,end}={E}; % Insert the expectation
    Av{i,end}={V}; % Insert standard deviation
end
```